# software to edit keyboard multimedia key bindings

Tags: keyboard, multimedia

my Datalink's prodot keyboard has 10 multimedia keys, but it didn't come with any cd having software to edit these, nor is there site having any download for this.

I don't use multimedia so I want to utilize these keys to other purposes.

Is there any software that will directly edit keyboard multimedia key so that I can bind them to other software I use?

I don't want direct registry hacks nor do I want to assign from "within" foobar or vlc as I don't use these or any multimedia things much.

Thanks.

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned there first.
W10-64 bit, w8.1-64 bit, I also have Ubuntu installed, though don't use that much.

Answer (score 2):

The best software for keyboard mapping is by using the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
to remap the keyboard, with an almost unlimited number of possibilities.

Media keys for AutoHotkey are listed in the article
[List of Keys - Multimedia Keys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#multimedia).

For example, here is a AutoHotkey script that will use the Mail key to
launch a program:

```
Launch_Mail::
Run, "C:\path\to\program.exe" parameters
return
```

Place the script in an `.ahk` file. Test by double-click to launch.
It will have a green "H" icon in the traybar, which you may right-click to Exit.
Once proven as working correctly, you may place it in your Startup folder.

To learn AutoHotkey, see the many tutorials on its website.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [MKey](http://web.archive.org/web/20190617222104/http://www.seriosoft.org/en/index.php).

It hasn't been updated since 2015, but still works decently and it's freeware.
It has a number of nice features, like OSD and direct audio player control.

Comment: Very easy convenient, compared to registry hacks. I defined multimedia "calc" key to open control panel, it opens control panel but also opens calc even now. I will have to figure out how to stop the original key binding. Its manual is probably in Russian so I can't read.

Comment: You could check this key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey about disabling these original bindings. Although I didn't tried it myself.

Comment: oh, I was not comfortable going through registry that is why I was asking for a standalone software able to do this. If no other method is there, I will have to touch registry. Thanks.