# Disabling advertising button on keyboard

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard

So I have this Chinese wireless keyboard, which has an advertising key, in place of the right alt button. It looks like this:

[image: Keyboard].

The advertising key when pressed, opens JD.com, a Chinese e-commerce site. I tried using [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys) to disable the key.

Unfortunately, the ad key is mapped to the left windows button (E0_5B), see 
[image: screenshot here]

The actual left windows button is mapped to this as well, which leaves me confused.

How do I disable this key on my keyboard? (I'm running Windows 8.1)

EDIT:

The command issued by the button is:

```
Windows + R (to open "Run"), followed by the URL, JD.com
```

Comment: It might be sending a set of keystrokes, and the first one is the windows key.

Comment: It appears to be that way, the command issued actually is: Win + R (open run), and enter the URL, JD.com.

Comment: You could try answers from this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1396549/software-to-edit-keyboard-multimedia-key-bindings)

Comment: Tried them, the key just shows up as Win+R and not the whole command that is issued, it doesn't appear to disable the key as such.

Comment: Do you use a specialized driver for that keyboard? If so it might be implementing this.

Comment: @Seth, I haven't installed any specialized driver. Just plugged in and started using it.

Answer (score 0):

This almost certainly hardware, Reptilian is right. I dabble in custom keyboards, and unless using a software able to intercept a full macro, your best best is to open the keyboard, and insert a piece of tape between the membrane and the PCB.

Here is a link to a keyboard repair video, where you can clearly see the rubber membrane removed, and the PCB underneath https://youtu.be/mC5P7IGR8-M?t=187

This should be easy to do, don't worry :)

Edit: By the way, AutoHotKey is a free piece of software which you can use for this purpose. When it detects "jd.com" is typed, you can tell it to first, "esc" (to exit the windows+R window), and then do whatever you want.

Comment: I figured the easiest solution would be to physically disable the key. I've removed the button and taped it over. But, there has to be a way to edit the keymappings right? 

I believe the in-built driver that came along with the device is causing the problem.

Comment: Your keyboard is likely using the standard HID driver, but it is its firmware you want to modify. Unfortunately, I don't think they put a reprogrammable firmware in a promo keyboard. Even if, I have no clue on how to reprogram it.